# Does Ecma-334 have an incorrect description for next line (C# ECMA Standard)?

Tags: c#, standards, ecma

In Ecma-334 (C# Language Specification 4th Edition), Annex A. Grammar, Section A.1.1 Line terminators:

```
new-line::
  Carriage return character (U+000D)
  Line feed character (U+000A)
  Carriage return character (U+000D) followed by line feed character (U+000A)
  Next line character (U+2085)
  Line separator character (U+2028)
  Paragraph separator character (U+2029)
```

But U+2085 is not the Next line character; it is `SUBSCRIPT FIVE`.

Does Ecma-334 have an incorrect description for Next line?

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2085/index.htm

**Edit**: (U+0085) is the Next line character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that appears to be an error in the standard.

The Microsoft C# language specification (the version shipped with VS2010) has the correct item:

```
Next line character (U+0085)
```

Comment: Do you think is it worth to report to ECMA?

Comment: @Amir, someone has already reported it. See [here](http://pastebin.com/n4HjZbid).